# Move Insertion point of an NSTextView and make the written content visible

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

[image]I am working on one Mac app. In which I want to play few tricks with insertion point of an NSTextView.

```
 ![NSTextView with overlay on it][2]
```

What am I doing is, I have an NSTextView (The whole image screen is of NSTextView) and above that I have placed one overlay (as you can see at the bottom of the image). There are two Labels at the extreme Left and Right end and has a white gradient view too. All these three I have placed above NSTextView.

Now when User types in, textview gets scrolled and at one point, typed letters goes below the overlay.

I have to manage this stuff only. I want to keep track that user has reached to the overlay border and if yes, I want to move the insertion point to little upside so that user can see the content which he/she is writing.

Will anyone suggest me, how to make this possible ?
     I have tried many things, but its not working. Kindly help.

Comment: Looks like you lost the screenshot you tried to post.

Comment: Hi Wil, Thanks for that. Do you get that now ?

Comment: Yes, very helpful. But I'm not clear on your English. You say you want to move the insertion point...do you mean you want to scroll the view up?

Comment: Yes Wil. The thing is, The container view (having "add a tag" and "812 words" and a gradient image view) at the bottom is placed above the NSTextView. 
So, the behaviour is- User types in, reaches to the bottom of the textView and because of the overlay view which we have placed, few bottom lines of NSTextView gets hidden.
I want to maintain that state and make the user to see everything he/she writes.
Do you get me ?